# Dynamics CRM Plugin can't retrieve records created earlier in the pipeline

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a chain of synchronous events that take place.

1. a custom control calls an action
2. action creates a couple of records
3. action then triggers a plugin which tries to retrieve records that were created in step 2, but the query returns nothing

I suspect this is happening because all the events are in the same transaction and therefore the records they create are not yet committed to the database.  Is this correct?

Is there an easy way to retrieve records that were created earlier in the pipeline or am I stuck having to stuff OutputParameter object into SharedVariables?

Comment: I guess the plugin is not participating in the transaction and therefore cannot access the records created earlier. How did you exactly register all events?

Comment: I just tried the exact same scenario you've outlined and I was able to access the created entity record. The plugin was registered `post-operation`, still called from within the action after create of the record.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your action, your plugin and how it's registered?